# How to know if the browser is pinning by the android screen pin

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I'm working on a web application that should always be visible on the tablet that opens.
To achieve this, what I have done is to use the 'Pin Screen' function of Android so that users who use the tablet do not leave the web application.

The problem that sometimes users leave in this way pressing the security keys.

For this reason I would like to know if there is any way from Javascript to know if the browser is pinning or not and thus be able to notify it on the server.

Comment: I highly doubt it. App pinning is an Android-specific API feature, and has nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: Hi @TheWanderer, I was thinking about some trick. For example, if opening a pop-up window does not open it is because it is pinning, but this trick does not work for me because if it is not pinning it opens the pop-up window, leaving the application.